# Suddenly my font changed, what happened and how?

Tags: 20.04, fonts

I was using my laptop, Ubuntu 20.04, and just went to the bathroom and when I am back, the font changed to this:
[image]

**Edit:**
I opened gnome-tweak, and found this (None) in the font family:
[image]

**Edit 2:**
It is fixed after setting the font in `gnome-tweak`, but why did this happen?

How did this happen?

I didn't do anything, I swear!

Comment: Also had this happen, but seemed to occur just on Chrome; it was a different font for me. Restarting the browser seemed to help.